# Why is Meteor causing my Q.defer() to prematurely return?

Tags: meteor, q

I've been using the Q library for Promises in my Meteor app, and recently hit a snag I'm struggling to understand, much less work around. The gist of it is that if I'm waiting on a Q.defer and the resolve callback for that defer tries to access a Mongo Collection, then the code waiting on that defer starts executing immediately instead of waiting for the defer's resolve callback to fully complete.

I don't observe this behavior when using other Q promises that are not Q.defer. Here is the leanest proof of concept I've been able to put together to demonstrate the issue:

```
let def = Q.defer()
Q.when(test_promise(def))
  .then(function() {
      console.log('this should be last')
    }
  )
def.resolve()

function test_promise(def) {
  return def.promise.then(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
    console.log('resolving deferred')
    SomeMongoCollection.remove('an_id') // Removing this line makes everything work as expected
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    }
    console.log('done with deferred promise')
  }))
}

/*
 * Output:
 * resolving deferred
 * this should be last
 * done with deferred promise
 */
```

My best guess is that this is something to do with Fibers and using Meteor.bindEnvironment, but without that the remove method hangs. I would greatly appreciate it if somebody could explain what Meteor is doing that's causing this behavior, and if there's any viable workaround.